# Definition of continuous distribution (intuitively understanding)

Tags: probability, statistics

Def: A continuous random variable is not defined at specific values. Instead, it is defined over an interval of values, and is represented by the area under a curve. The probability of observing any single value is equal to 0, since the number of values which may be assumed by the random variable is infinite.

I dont really understand the second sentence. And it would be really helpful if there is a concrete example for the explanation.

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

If the value of the variable is $v$ and the number of possible values it can take is $n$, then the probability that it will take on the specific value $v'$ is $1/n$.

If the variable is continuous then $n$ equals infinity and the probability $1/n$ is zero.

For example, if $v$ can take on any value in the interval [0,1] then the probability that it will be equal to 0.012345 is zero--because there are an infinite number of possible values.  However the probability that it will take on some value between 0 and 0.5 is 50%.

Note that if $v$ was discrete and could take on only a finite number of values, say $n$ equal to $k$, the probability that it takes on a particular value would be non zero, and equal to $1/k$.

Answer (score 1):

@user45664's answer is correct, but I'll explain a slightly different way.  Suppose we have an interval from 0 to 1, containing just the values 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, and 0.9. That's nine values.  The probability of choosing, say, 0.4 in that interval at random is 1/9.

Now increase the set of values to include more: 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, etc.: a total of 19 values.  The probability of choosing any given value in that interval at random is now 1/19.

If you keep increasing the number of values, with adjacent values being closer and closer together, the number of values approaches infinity.  At the same time, the probability of choosing any given value in the interval approaches 1/infinity.  1/infinity is zero.